# Connecting a Heart Rate Monitor to a Windows PC Java application

Tags: java, windows, bluetooth, heartbeat

I'm currently working on a project which requires my java program to keep track of a users current heart rate. Now, my problem is that i seem to be unable to find any sort of heart rate monitor which is able to connect to a java program running on a Windows PC.

I'm currently experimenting with a Polar H7 Bluetooth smart ready heart rate monitor and i'm trying to get it to connect with my PC which has a Bluetooth 4.0 adapter(Bluetooth smart) but it seems to be leading to a dead end.

Comment: I don't think its that relevant if it connects to java. Have you found one that you can connect to a computer - USB is probably simpler than bluetooth. Even if the libraries are C/C++, you could easily write JNI interfaces to get access.

Comment: Honestly no, and i have searched for a while for a Heart Rate Monitor  that connects to a PC, but most seem to only be compatible with certain Smart Phones.

Comment: To add on to @drone.ah - If you found one that connects to the computer, you could most likely find a spec for it and write the corresponding java library yourself instead of JNI.